# What is are digitally-mated pairs

Tags: wheeled-robot

I am considering competing in the robogames, but the rules require that R/C bots have  digitally-mated pairs. I am not sure what these pairs are. For reference here are the rules for robot sumo and combots.
[Robot Sumo Rules](http://robogames.net/rules/all-sumo.php)

[Combot Rules](http://robogames.net/rules/combat.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have to make sure that your remote talks only to your own robot and you doesn't interfere with the commands of other robots. This could be an encryption so that no other robot understands your commands.

From [Combat Robot Rules](http://robogames.net/rules/combat.php):

> All robots (including insect classes) MUST use a radio system with digitally coded, mated pairs between transmitter and receiver. This means that no other transmitter, operating on the same frequency, can communicate with your receiver, and your transmitter cannot send signals to any receiver other than your own. Examples of such systems are Spektrum, IFI, and XPS XtremeLink - these are just examples and should not be taken as a comprehensive list or an endorsement.